# Inserting figures with LP extension in a Latex document

Tags: graphics

I have created figures with extension LP in `latexcad` and I want to include them in a file with LaTeX. How I can do it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `pdflatex` can only import PNG, PDF and JPEG images. Other formats must be converted.

Answer (score 1):

The [latexcad](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexcad) package produces files containing LaTeX commands. You just need to copy and paste the commands into your document, or load the files with `\input`.